# javascript processing an array of objects to obtain a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to obtain from a given array of objects another array of objects but a little bit processed. Example:

```
 var arr =   [
      {
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "B"
      },{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "C"
      },{
        "level": "INC",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "B"
      }
]
```

`process_array(arr)`

should return:

```
      [{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "A-B-C"
      },{
        "level": "INC",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "A-D"
      }]
```

I mean, there only will be one object per different level and all the different models for that level will be concatenated by '-'.

What would be an easy way to achieve so?

My approach, for getting an array with different levels:

```
function process_array(array) {
    var values_seen = {}; // for removing duplicates
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        values_seen[array[i]["level"]] = true;
    }
    return Object.keys(values_seen);
}
```

Now i need to obtain the concatented models for each levels..

Comment: You should add the code you've already tried to your question.

Comment: shortly edited with how I have started...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reduce the array into an object:

```
return array.reduce(function(total, current) {
  if (total[current.level]) { // existing
    total[current.level].model += '-' + current.model;
  } else { // new
    total[current.level] = current;
  }
  return total;
}, {});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ranaqipuga/1/)

In each iteration you modify the `total` object and then return it to be used within the next iteration. The final value of that object is returned to the caller.

See also [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Smart! Didn't think of using reduce like that.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr =   [
      {
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "B"
      },{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "C"
      },{
        "level": "INC",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "B"
      }
]

function processArray(array) {
    
    var count = array.length, i, item, result = [], temp = {};
    
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        item = array[i];
      
        if (temp[item.level] !== undefined) {
            result[temp[item.level]].model += '-' + item.model;        
        } else {
            temp[item.level] = result.length;
            result.push(item);
        }
        
    }

    return result;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(processArray(arr)));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is also called projection.

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffijoe/1brsLtvt/1/) uses EcmaScript 5.

```
var arr =   [
      {
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "B"
      },{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "C"
      },{
        "level": "INC",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "B"
      }
];

function processArray(input) {
    var buf = {}, result = [];
    input.forEach(function(item) {
        var model = item.model;
        var existing = buf[item.level];
        if (existing) {
           existing.model += '-' + item.model;         
        } else {
            existing = buf[item.level] = {
                level: item.level,
                model: model
            };
            result.push(existing);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var processed = processArray(arr);
console.log(processed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function processArray(arr) {
    var result = [];
    arr
        .map(function(v) {return v.level;})
        .forEach(function(v, i) {
            var resultValue = result.filter(function(el, j) {
                return el.level === v;
            })[0];

            if(!resultValue) {
              result.push(arr[i]); 
            } else {
              resultValue.model += '-' + arr[i].model;
            }
        });
    return result;
}

var arr = [
      {
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "B"
      },{
        "level": "INF",
        "model": "C"
      },{
        "level": "INC",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "A"
      },{
        "level": "IND",
        "model": "B"
      }
];

alert(JSON.stringify(processArray(arr), null, 2));
```